# How to Create UILabel Within an UIImageView right side which match any Text length?

Tags: ios7, uiimageview, uilabel

I want to create an `UILabel` programmatically. It should be placed on the bottom of the right side of an `UIImageView` But the text that i am going to assign to the label is not a fixed size,, It may be vary from item to item. I want to create this label to show these text without decreasing the font size. Can anybody show me the correct way to achieve these tasks.

Thanks

This is the cell I wanted. these price and, title labels I want to create programmatically

[image]

Comment: Use right-aligned labels combined with auto layout constraints that offset the bottom and trailing edges of the labels.

Comment: you can set  UILabel to right side with NoOfRows=2